# How to write data to a .csv file as an extra column

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I have a csv file like this

```
NAME, BANK ACCOUNT, SORT CODE, INVESTMENT
 A     123            XXX         1000
 B     456            XXX         2000
 C     789            XXX         3000
```

I want to add an extra column that makes the file look like

```
NAME, BANK ACCOUNT, SORT CODE, INVESTMENT, Contribution
 A     123            XXX         1000         16.67
 B     456            XXX         2000         33.33
 C     789            XXX         3000          50
```

I have worked out a `float percentage` that contains all the elements required and now I am confused about how to add it to the data file as an extra line.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

#define W1 0.2

vector<float>Data_investment;
string Trim(string& str);

string Trim(string& str)
{

    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n"));
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(" \t\r\n") + 1);
    return str;
}

void Get_Data(const string& s, vector<float>& data)
{
    ifstream fin(s);
    string line;
    int flag = 0;
    while (getline(fin, line))
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            istringstream sin(line);
            vector<string> fields;
            string field;
            while (getline(sin, field, ',')) 
            {
                fields.push_back(field);  
            }
            string investment = Trim(fields[3]);
            data.push_back(atof(const_cast<const char*>(investment.c_str())));
        }
        ++flag;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Get_Data("aaa.csv", Data_investment);

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto i : Data_investment) {
        sum += i;
    }

    float total = accumulate(Data_investment.begin(), Data_investment.end(), 0);
    const unsigned int quantity = Data_investment.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
    {
        float percentage = (Data_investment[i] * 100.0f) / total;
        cout << percentage << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would have to read in the existing file, and for each line add the extra column data as needed and write the new line out to a new file, then replace the old file with the new file when done

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you please show me how to add the extra column data for each line?

Comment: You are already reading the existing lines as strings, so what is stopping you from simply appending the new column data to the end of each string when writing it back out?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I mean the data I want to append is presented as float and I don't know how to put it into the csv file in the form the figure above.

Comment: Again, what is stopping you from simply taking data you already have from the original file for any given line, appending the new column data to the end of that, and writing that to a new file? Please be more specific about what exactly you need help with. Take the first line `NAME, BANK ACCOUNT, SORT CODE, INVESTMENT`, append `Contribution` to the end of it, and save it to the new file.  Take the second line `A     123            XXX         1000`, append `16.67` to the end of it, and save it to the new file.  And so on for the rest of the remaining lines.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry I don't know any function that can append the data to the end of the line...

Comment: So, you are saying you don't know how to append values to the end of a `std::string`? Or how to write values to an `std::ostream` using `operator<<` before writing a line break to it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know either of them. I am just a beginner in C++.

Comment: <sigh> You should have lead with that. I have posted an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

struct Investment
{
    string Name;
    string BankAccount;
    string SortCode;
    float Investment;
    float Contribution;
};

string Trim(string str)
{
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n"));
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(" \t\r\n") + 1);
    return str;
}

void Get_Data(const string &filename, vector<Investment> &data)
{
    ifstream fin(filename);
    if (!fin.is_open())
        return;

    string line;
    if (!getline(fin, line))
        return;

    while (getline(fin, line))
    {
        istringstream sin(line);
        vector<string> fields;
        string field;

        while (getline(sin, field, ','))
        {
            fields.push_back(field);  
        }

        Investment inv;
        inv.Name = Trim(fields[0]);
        inv.BankAccount = Trim(fields[1]);
        inv.SortCode = Trim(fields[2]);
        inv.Investment = atof(Trim(fields[3]).c_str());
        inv.Contribution = 0.0f;

        data.push_back(inv);
    }
}

void Save_Data(const string &filename, const vector<Investment> &data)
{
    ofstream fout(filename);
    if (!fout.is_open())
        return;

    fout << "NAME,BANK ACCOUNT,SORT CODE,INVESTMENT,Contribution\n";

    for (auto &inv : data)
    {
        fout << inv.Name << ","
            << inv.BankAccount << ","
            << inv.SortCode << ","
            << inv.Investment << ","
            << inv.Contribution << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<Investment> Data_investment;
    Get_Data("aaa.csv", Data_investment);

    float total = accumulate(Data_investment.begin(), Data_investment.end(), 0.0f,
        [](float sum, const Investment &inv){ return sum + inv.Investment; }
    );

    for (auto &inv : Data_investment)
    {
        inv.Contribution = (inv.Investment * 100.0f) / total;
    }

    Save_Data("aaa_new.csv", Data_investment);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ewVtQm)

Comment: Sorry, but it not working. Error link is threw  Error: Unable to open file C:\Users...\test1\Debug\investment.obj. Error code = 0x80070002

Comment: That is not a compiler error. In any case, I found a few minor mistakes in the code and corrected them. See the [working demo](https://ideone.com/ewVtQm) I added a link to